# Can I install Micosoft Office Home and Student 2010 on my Windows 64 bit XP machine?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

I have a 64 bit version of Windows XP, and am wondering if I can install Microsoft Office Home and Student 2010 on it. Some of my friends are telling me that I can't install this version of Office on a 64 bit Windows XP machine.

I checked the files on the disc, and it has a 32 bit and 64 bit option.  Can I install the 32 bit version on my 64 bit Windows XP machine?

Thanks for any help

Comment: 'Some of my friends are telling me that I can't install this version of Office on a 64 bit Windows XP machine.' - Does Microsoft said the same thing? If no, then imho it is safe to do it. ( :

Answer (score 0):

looks like this version only works on Vista, 7, or Server 2008 ;( Although I guess it wouldnt hurt to try it? Might not work though.
Operating systems required to run 64-bit version of Office

Your computer must be running at least 64-bit edition Windows 7, 64-bit edition Windows Vista, or 64-bit edition Windows Server 2008.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-office-HA010369476.aspx